# Unable to get the other details of the users in the friend's list of fb?

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

This is the code that i used.I am only able to get the name and ids of the friends and no other details

```
    FacebookClient fb=new DefaultFacebookClient(ACCESS_TOKEN);  

    Connection<User> myFriends = fb.fetchConnection("me/friends", User.class);

    List<User> users=myFriends.getData();

    for(Iterator iterator=users.iterator();iterator.hasNext();)

    {
        User user=(User)iterator.next();

        System.out.println(user.getRelationshipStatus());

    }
```

Comment: What's the output? Do you get `null` or is an Exception thrown?

Comment: Im getting the output as null and I have enabled all sorts of permissions that I can possibly include from the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting only the name and id is the expected result.

You can change it by specifying which fields you want to get back. In restfb it should be something like:

```
Connection<User> myFriends = fb.fetchConnection("me/friends", User.class, 
    Parameter.with("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,name,gender"));
```

Add anything else you need and have permission for.

Comment: Thank you.I have the permission for almost everything like for users and for the friends!....But still after adding the location field to it Im getting the output as null when i print user.getLocation() .

Comment: Sometimes you don't get, as an application, friend fields that you can see as a user. Probably a privacy setting... try the [Facebook Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to test stuff

Comment: The facebook graph Explorer also gives me the same result.While I can see the complete details of the logged in users account,the details of the friends are restricted to id,firstname,lastname,name,link,gender,locale,updated time and guser.As you suggested had altered the privacy settings from custom to friends,but still the problem is persisting.

Comment: I just opened the graph explorer, hit "Get Access Token", gave "friends_location" permission, and typed `me/friends?fields=id,name,location`. It works. Check the permissions again

Comment: Thanks a million!....I had generated the access token using the url.So had a bit of confusion in dealing with it.Never knew  a particular access have been granted or not.Now it works!...Thank u again!....